# Problem with Webview showing Google Photos in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

I am using flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11

This is my code

Widget build(BuildContext context){

return WebviewScaffold(

url: glbPhotoURL,

withJavascript: true,

scrollBar : true,

withZoom: true
)

url: glbPhotoURL => here glbPhotoURL is a URL that I am passing
When I am using any normal URL it is running fine (like http://www.google.com, http://youtube.com"
Even url like - https://youtu.be/o5UPfG1eIw4 is running fine

But when I am using any google photo url (short url) it is throwing an error net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME for eg - https://photos.app.goo.gl/FkQenAD8kQQc4TSr6

If I am using the expanded URL it shows the pictures -https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNItZG3Cg_hn9__2QnuVh3nNMbRuGxQaQSWZ76qni7L7h0ORbauolcH3AKe0MOnEA?
key=emc1Mk1CenRJRjloMjV5V1AzcmczNUprcGFsbmR3

Please help me resolve the issue
As of now I am running it on Android physical device.

Comment: URL : https://photos.app.goo.gl/FkQenAD8kQQc4TSr6 

E/chromium(13502): [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
E/chromium(13502): [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
W/cr_media(13502): Requires MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS and RECORD_AUDIO. No audio device will be available for recording

to be on the safer side - I gave the following permissions in Android Manifest (Internet, Camera, Record Audio, Modify Audio Setting Video Capture and Audio Capture

Comment: Well - I resolved it at the server level- Its a workaround - I created an API at the server which accepts the URL - in turn it generates the call back url - and this URL I am storing in the Database - which now I am calling from the flutter app and it runs like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Google Photos uses Firebase Dynamic Links. I suggest launching the link externally. I encountered a similar error on Android before, when Firebase Dynamic Links are being forced to be loaded in a WebView. FDLs are expected to be handled by Google Play Services in Android. But since the WebView doesn't know what to do with the link it's forced to display, the WebView returns "net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" error.

Open the link externally by using [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). Use RegEx to filter intent URLs and check if the URL can be launched and be handled externally (outside the app).

```dart
var yourURL = "URL goes here";
// Check if URL contains Google Photos URL
yourURL.contains(RegExp('^https://photos\.app\.goo\.gl/.*$')){
  // Check if the URL can be launched
  if (await canLaunch(yourURL)) {
    await launch(yourURL);
  } else {
    print('Could not launch $yourURL');
  }
}
```